# How to convert a postgres timestamp to a string with the timezone as numeric offset?

Tags: postgresql, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

My query needs to format my `timestamp without time zone`columns into a format which in Java I can obtain like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ")
```

For example:
`2015-12-21T16:29:07.000-06:00` or `2016-04-18T10:10:09.000+0000`

Now, I know the format wants a timezone, but it's OK to assume timezone = UTC.

What I tried:

```
select to_char(updated_at, 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZZ') from teams
2016-04-07'T'05:04:47.47SZZZZZZ

select to_char(updated_at::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZZ') from teams
2016-04-07'T'05:04:47.47SZZZZZZ
```

Also tried with postgres' 'tz' and 'TZ' it's just not capable to output a numeric timezone!

```
select to_char(updated_at::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS TZ') from teams
2016-04-07'T'05:04:47.47 BST
```

I just can't get the numeric representation of the timezone, is this intentional? :(

Comment: [from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) **`OF` time-zone offset**

Comment: I have NO IDEA how I missed that. I read 3,4 times the two lines above it.

Comment: and what about postgres prior to v9.4  ??  No OF code supported there!